# How to get python to copy files to desktop

Tags: python

How do I make python copy a jpeg to the desktop?

```
import shutil
src = ('1.3.jpg')
dst = ('tEST/nicholas')
count = 1
while count < 10000000000:
    shutil.copyfile(src, dst + str(count) + ".jpg")
    count += 1
```

This is what I have so far but I want to change the dst folder into the desktop I'm using windows 7

Comment: For me it is `~/Desktop`, but you didn't tell us which OS you're on

Comment: I'm using windows 7 as my OS

Comment: see: https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile

Answer (score 2):

Just define absolute adress of your desktop.

```
dst = 'C:\\Users\\[name of your account]\\myfile.txt'
```

Comment: Could also use `os.environ['USERHOME'] + '/Desktop/myfiles'`, if you wanted to be more portable.

Comment: `~/Downloads` works on Windows 10